# Restore file I deleted from git stage?

Tags: git

I wrote up a lot of files of code and used git add . in my working branch and forgot to commit it. I wasn't sure why the files were showing up my master branch so I went into intellij to delete them. Now they aren't showing up my working branch and I obviously don't have them committed and saved.

I wanted to ask if there's a way to restore them?

I tried to search in my trash but Intellij doesn't put deleted files in the trash.

I tried using local history but it doesn't show those particular files. It only shows other changes. However when I tried to revert to the time of those other changes. The files were not restored.

Comment: `git reflog` will help you

Comment: Did you check Local History for the directory that contained those files?

Comment: Can you screenshot of:

`git status`

and 

`git reflog` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check Local History. I used git reflog but it didn't show those files when I looked through the SHAs. However the situation didn't end up being a big deal since I apparently had a file that was similar enough to those files I couldn't recover where it'd be easy toe rewrite those files.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status | grep 'deleted:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git checkout --
```

This might help. Also check traces in `git reflog`

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote up a lot of files of code and used git add . in my working branch and forgot to commit it [and then removed some of these files]

Uh oh.  There is a *chance* you can get stuff back, but it's not so easy.

When you actually commit stuff, Git makes a snapshot, using whatever you have in your staging area at that time.  The staging area is initially filled from some existing commit.

Anything you have ever `git add`-ed, that was a totally new file or that you had changed in your work-tree files, went into Git's *index*.  The index doesn't actually contain *files*, though.  Instead, it contains *file names*, a mode (`100644` for non-executable files, and `100755` for executable files), and a *hash ID* of an internal Git *blob object*.  This is both good and bad, as we'll see in a moment.

When you then deleted the files, Git removed the copies from both your work-tree and the index.  Your work-tree isn't actually in the repository at all, in a pretty strong sense, so *those* files cannot be recovered by Git.  (If you have Time Machine on a Mac, or other methods for recovering files, those are worth considering.  Apparently IntelliJ does keep some extra copies, but based on your question, it looks like it didn't, this time.)

The index, however, *is* in the repository—sort of.  It's in a part that is never copied by `git clone`, but it is in the `.git` directory.  Unfortunately, it's *temporary:* it hangs on to the information Git will need for the next `git commit`, and other information that helps Git go fast and do useful stuff, but when you removed the files, Git removed the index entries that kept track of their <name, mode, hash-ID> tuple.

The good news part of this is that those `hash-ID`s refer to Git *blob* objects, and blob objects *are* in the repository.  They may be *referenced* through an index entry, or by being stored in a commit—technically, in a *tree* object—or they may be entirely *unreferenced*.  When you create a totally new file that has *content* that has never been committed, and run `git add path/to/file`, Git makes a new blob object and stores that in the repository, and puts the reference in the index.

Assuming this file content still doesn't match any other file content, but also that the index entry was removed without ever committing, there is no *tree* object that refers to this Git blob, and there is no index entry that refers to this Git blob.  So this blob is *unreachable*, and `git gc` will eventually remove it entirely.

It takes at least 14 days before `git gc` removes an unreachable blob object.  This gives Git commands like `git add` 14 days to create them and then arrange for them to be referenced (e.g., to have their hash ID stored in Git's index).  If your `git add` happened *less than 14 days ago*, this grace period is keeping the blob objects alive.

You can now run:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

Git will, slowly and painfully, iterate over *every Git object in the entire Git objects database* (this can take many seconds) to verify that it looks valid and is *referenced* by *something*.  Anything suffices: a branch name, a commit hash, a tree object, and so on.  Your new files, however, won't be referenced, so they will be *unreferenced blob objects* which will also (by definition in this case) be *dangling blobs*.<sup>1</sup>

The `--lost-found` argument tells Git: *for each dangling commit or blob, print a message about it and insert something into the `.git/lost-found/` directory*.  For these blob objects, Git expands out the compressed data and stores it in `.git/lost-found/others/`.  So running `git fsck lost-found` will populate this directory.

You can now:

```
cd .git/lost-found/others
```

and look at each file.  They will have hash-ID names, but some of them will be the *content* you added using `git add`.

Any content you added that exactly matched some existing committed file content won't be a dangling blob—Git will have re-used the existing blob, and that blob is still referenced through the existing commit.  But you can get some, maybe most or all, of your work back, except for the lack of correct file names (and modes).

If the 14 day grace period has expired, you may still get lucky: `git gc` doesn't run until something else triggers it, so the dangling blobs may still be present.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git fsck --lost-found` command does this same kind of checking for commit objects.  Commits can also be unreferenced—not reachable from a name—*and* dangling, or *unreachable* but not *dangling* because they're reachable from a commit that itself is dangling, or *reachable* and therefore not dangling.  So for commits, there's a useful distinction.  For blobs, there isn't.